# How to assign variable values to cells to avoid VBA run-time error 5?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to assign the value of some user input (generated through forms) to a specific cell. That is, if my rowLocation variable = 4, I'd like cell C4(what I'm calling statusRng) to have the value of CaseStatusBox.Text.

When I run what I currently have, I get run-time error 5: "invalid procedure call or argument" on the line commented out in the code below. Any ideas where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

```
rowLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(client, rng, 0)

statusRng = ("C" & rowLocation)
StaffRng = ("D" & rowLocation)
DateRng = ("G" & rowLocation)


OutputSheet.Cells("statusRng") = CaseStatusBox.Text 'debugger points to error on this line
OutputSheet.Cells("StaffRng") = StaffEntryBox.Text
OutputSheet.Cells("DateRng") = Date
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `.Range(statusRng)` (etc.) instead of `.Cells("statusRng")` (etc.).

Comment: Changing to .Range(variable) results in the 1004 error, method range of object ' _Worksheet' failed. For reference, the variables 'statusRng' currently evaluates to "C1"

Comment: Looks like you misread @Comintern's comment and forgot to remove the `"` double qutoes aka string literal delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

`Worksheet.Cells` returns a `Range` object, and doesn't take any parameters; the `("statusRng")` argument you're passing, is going to end up passed to the `Range.[_Default]` property, which takes 2 optional arguments. Given arguments, `Range.[_Default]` passes them to `Range.Item(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)`, which accepts integer/`Long` values, not strings.

As [@Comintern suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373083/how-to-assign-variable-values-to-cells-to-avoid-vba-run-time-error-5#comment95560672_54373083), passing the arguments to `Worksheet.Range` instead, would work as expected - `Worksheet.Range` accepts `[cell1], [cell2]` arguments that are `Variant`, and provide several convenient ways to retrieve a `Range` out of a `Worksheet` object - one of which is to supply the name of a named range.

Therefore, these should work just fine, provided the specified names exist:

```
OutputSheet.Range("statusRng").Value = CaseStatusBox.Text
OutputSheet.Range("StaffRng").Value = StaffEntryBox.Text
OutputSheet.Range("DateRng").Value = Date
```

If the names don't exist, expect run-time error 1004.

Looks like you mean to pass string variables containing worksheet addresses, not named ranges. In that case, drop the `"` double quotes, since these delimit string literals in VBA; the `"statusRng"` string is being passed, and your `statusRng` variable isn't being read.

```
Dim statusRng As String
statusRng = "C" & rowLocation

Dim StaffRng As String
StaffRng = "D" & rowLocation

Dim DateRng As String
DateRng = "G" & rowLocation

OutputSheet.Range(statusRng).Value = CaseStatusBox.Text
OutputSheet.Range(StaffRng).Value = StaffEntryBox.Text
OutputSheet.Range(DateRng).Value = Date
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `statusRng` is a string. Then I would skip the brackets in the line and skip the quotes in the lines below. Like this:

```
rowLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(client, rng, 0)

statusRng = "C" & rowLocation
StaffRng = "D" & rowLocation
DateRng = "G" & rowLocation


OutputSheet.Range(statusRng) = CaseStatusBox.Text 'debugger points to error on this line
OutputSheet.Range(StaffRng) = StaffEntryBox.Text
OutputSheet.Range(DateRng) = Date
```

Edit: I now see that Matthieu was a couple of minutes ahead of me with a comprehensive answer ;-)